# Trying to figure out how to make this n queens method stop once it gets all all of the solutions, what are some ways to approach this problem?

Tags: java, stack, n-queens

I am working on the good ol' N-queens problem using a stack instead of recursive calls in order to find the total number of solutions for N Queens. I believe that the program I have works, except I am having trouble figuring out how to break out of the loop which finds the solutions.  What are some ways to go about this?

This is for one of my computer science classes, using java.  I've already tried what my friend suggested, to have the condition for the while be while the current row is within the board, but that caused some problems with stopping the solution search before a solution could be found.  I also tried to break out of the loop when the size of the stack was 1, but that only worked when N = 4, not for larger values of N, the program may also not work for N > 4, haven't tested that quite yet.

EmptyStackException when N = 5 and when

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.EmptyStackException
    at java.base/java.util.Stack.peek(Stack.java:102)
    at java.base/java.util.Stack.pop(Stack.java:84)
    at Assignment22.stacker(Assignment22.java:61)
    at Assignment22.main(Assignment22.java:11)
```

```java
// gets number of solutions to N Queens
public static int stacker(boolean[][] board, int numQueens) {
        Stack<Integer> queensPos = new Stack<Integer>();
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int numSolutions = 0;

        // need to figure out how to tell program to
        // go back to previous row and remove queen
        // if col = 3 and row = 1, queen will always be placed there
        // however if queen is placed there, there is no solution
        // if row being worked on is in the board
        while (row <= board.length) {
            // if you have no more queens to place
            if (numQueens == 0) {
                // you have a solution
                for (int i = 0; i < queensPos.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(queensPos.get(i));
                }
                numSolutions += 1;
                // go back to last row
                row -= 1;
                // remove queen
                col = queensPos.pop();
                board[row][col] = false;
                // go back one row
                //row -= 1;
                numQueens += 1;
                col += 1;

            } else {
                // if there is a conflict and column is within board
                if (IsConflictPresent(board, row, col) && col < board[row].length - 1) {
                    // shift queen rightward
                    col += 1;
                // if column is out of board
                } else if (IsConflictPresent(board, row, col) && col == board[row].length - 1) {
                    // look at value of column, if it is at end of board
                    // go back to previous row
                    // looks at top of stack
                    col = queensPos.pop();  // <- EmptyStackException occurs here

                    if (row > 0) {
                        row -= 1;
                    }
                    board[row][col] = false;
                    numQueens += 1;
                    // attempt to solve problem where queen at end of 2nd row would keep getting placed
                    // appears to be working
                    if (!(col < board[row].length - 1)) {
                        col = queensPos.pop();

                        row -= 1;
                        board[row][col] = false;
                        numQueens += 1;
                        col += 1;
                    } else {
                        col += 1;
                    }
                } else  {
                // if queen can be placed
                    // place queen at row, col
                    board[row][col] = true;
                    queensPos.push(col);
                    numQueens -= 1;
                    // move to next row
                    row += 1;
                    // start at beginning of row
                    col = 0;

                    // when the below code is put in, EmptyStackException occurs when numQueens = 5
                    if (queensPos.size() == 1) {
                        row -= 1;
                        col = queensPos.pop();
                        numQueens += 1;
                    } 

                }
            }

        }
        return numSolutions;
    }

public static boolean IsConflictPresent(boolean[][] boardToCheck, int row, int col) {

        // figure out how to check one diagonal

        int i,j;
        int N = boardToCheck.length;
        // use 4 for loops
        // check on left side of row specified
        for (i = 0; i <= col; i++) {
            if (boardToCheck[row][i])
            {
                return true;
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < boardToCheck[row].length - 1; i++) {
            if (boardToCheck[i][col]) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        // to check diagonal, start at row 0 column 0, go up to row and column specified
        // upper diag on left side

        for (i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j >= 0; i--, j--) {
            if (boardToCheck[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // upper right diagonal check
        for (i = row, j = col; i >= 0 && j < N; i--, j++) {
            if (boardToCheck[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // lower diagonal on left side
        for (i = row, j = col; j >= 0 && i < N; i++, j--) {
            if (boardToCheck[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        // lower diagonal on right side
        for (i = row, j = col; j < N && i < N; i++, j++) {
            if (boardToCheck[i][j]) {
                return true;
            }
        }


        return false;
    }
```

I expect the program to eventually stop, but I get an infinite loop, and, depending on the fixes I've tried, an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or an EmptyStackException

Comment: "an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException or an EmptyStackException" What exceptions? Please edit your post to include the full error message, and the line that caused it. (We can't see line numbers in stack overflow)

Comment: Edited to include error message and at what line the exception occurs

Comment: We cannot see line numbers. Please display which lines caused the error by other means.

Comment: The line where the exception occurs is labeled with a comment next to it, below the comment "// if column is out of board"

Comment: You never place anything in the `Stack` queensPos in the method `stacker`.

Comment: In the entire program?  Every time a queen is added, the position of that queen is pushed onto the stack

Comment: `public static int stacker(boolean[][] board, int numQueens) {
        Stack<Integer> queensPos = new Stack<Integer>();` I was referring strictly inside the method. This stack right here.

Comment: below the comment saying "if queen can be placed" the value of col is pushed to the queensPos stack.  Regardless of the EmptyStackException though, how would i go about breaking out of the while loop after all possible solutions have been found?

Comment: `if(queensPos.isEmpty()) break;`

Comment: Uhh I don't think that will work, in the code if you have a case where the queen on the first row needs to be shifted to the right, the stack is empty.  Putting that conditional in would cause the loop to stop before a solution is found

Comment: After a lot of debugging, I managed to get my program to work properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My main issue that I found was that queens could not be placed anywhere in the last column when N  > 4, so I modified this conditional

```java
if (!(col < board[row].length - 1)) {
                        col = queensPos.pop();

                        row -= 1;
                        board[row][col] = false;
                        numQueens += 1;
                        col += 1;
                    } else {
                        col += 1;
                    }
```

and added the condition that row > 0

final stacker method:

```java
    public static int stacker(boolean[][] board, int numQueens) {
        Stack<Integer> queensPos = new Stack<Integer>();
        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;
        int numSolutions = 0;
        int colLastUsed = 0;
        // need to figure out how to tell program to
        // go back to previous row and remove queen
        // if col = 3 and row = 1, queen will always be placed there
        // however if queen is placed there, there is no solution
        // if row being worked on is in the board
        while (row <= board.length) {
            // if you have no more queens to place
            if (numQueens == 0) {
                // you have a solution
                for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; j++) {
                        if (board[i][j]) {
                            System.out.print("Q");
                        } else {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
                System.out.println();
                /*for (int i = 0; i < queensPos.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.print(queensPos.get(i) +" ");
                }
                System.out.println();*/
                numSolutions += 1;
                // go back to last row
                row -= 1;
                // remove queen
                col = queensPos.pop();
                board[row][col] = false;
                // go back one row
                //row -= 1;
                numQueens += 1;
                if (col < board.length - 1) {
                    // add one to col if it is not at end of row
                    col += 1;
                } else {
                    // go back another row
                    row -= 1;
                    col = queensPos.pop();

                    board[row][col] = false;

                    numQueens += 1;
                    col += 1;
                }
            // if there is a conflict and column is within board

            } else {
                if (col == board[row].length && row == 0) {
                    break;
                } else if (IsConflictPresent(board, row, col) && col < board[row].length - 1) {
                    // shift queen rightward
                    col += 1;
                    // if column is out of board
                } else if (IsConflictPresent(board, row, col) && col == board[row].length - 1) {
                    // look at value of column, if it is at end of board
                    // go back to previous row
                    // looks at top of stack
                    col = queensPos.pop();

                    if (row > 0) {
                        row -= 1;
                    }
                    board[row][col] = false;
                    numQueens += 1;
                    // attempt to solve problem where queen at end of 2nd row would keep getting placed
                    // appears to be working
                    if (!(col < board[row].length - 1) && row > 0) {
                        col = queensPos.pop();

                        row -= 1;
                        board[row][col] = false;
                        numQueens += 1;
                        col += 1;
                    } else {
                        col += 1;
                    }
                    // how to check to see if the column number you used
                } else {
                    // if queen can be placed
                    // place queen at row, col
                    board[row][col] = true;
                    queensPos.push(col);
                    numQueens -= 1;
                    // move to next row
                    row += 1;
                    // start at beginning of row
                    col = 0;

                }
            }

        }
        return numSolutions;
    }
```